# creating multi step moderation workflow in wagtail

Tags: wagtail-snippet

I have a requirement around creating multi step moderation workflow in `Wagtail`. Can somebody help in how to achieve it? Below is the use case

- step 1 - a *content creator* (i.e anyone with an account on the site
  that has been approved) creates a piece of content (article, photo,
  etc.) and submits that piece of content for review.
- step 2 - the content is reviewed by a *reviewer* - usually a teacher or
  staff member. If the article is approved by the *reviewer*, it is
  submitted to the editors for review and publication, if not it is
  sent back to the *content creator*
- step 3 - an *editor*, usually a student, reviews the submitted content
  from the *reviewer*, and either publishes the content, or sends it back
  to the *content creator* for changes.

Answer (score 0):

I am also starting a wagtail project requiring multi-steps validation and writer management.

Here's what I've gathered so far:

- Creating a Page based model with a `state` field and overriding the admin form to allow only the next state step for that user would get you a long way. You can make this field readonly an trigger the change via some custom buttons (see [register-page-listing-buttons](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/reference/hooks.html#register-page-listing-buttons)).
- You can use the [wagtail-review](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail-review) application. The Review model is overridable to add custom model/form fields/logic. You can use the related Permissions in a new Group, and only show the review button if the permission allows it.
- An [RFC for Immutable Revision Events](https://github.com/wagtail/rfcs/blob/master/text/029-immutable-revision-events.md) has been made, but not much progress has been done so far. Up to us to champion it, I invite you to join the #editorial-review channel in the Wagtail slack (wagtailcms.slack.com) to discuss about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older issue, however there is now a built in support for multi-step moderation workflows in Wagtail as of version 2.10.

### Overview

- [Wagtail 2.10](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/releases/2.10.html#moderation-workflow) introduced Moderation Workflow
- The workflow described in the question can now be 100% achieved via the Admin UI only.

### Instructions

Note: These are CMS Admin instructions and do not require any code, however for more complex use cases it is possible to [create custom Task types](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/custom_tasks.html).

1. Click Settings > Workflows
2. Click 'Add a Workflow'
3. Give the workflow a name: 'Student approval'
4. In the section 'add tasks to your workflow', click 'add' & then 'choose a task.
5. Task 1 - Name: 'Staff review' (this will map to step 2 in the question), and select the user Group 'Staff' (assuming this user group has been created).
6. Task 2 - Name: 'Student approval' (this will map to step 3 in the question), and select the user Group 'Students'.
7. Assign workflow to pages - select the parent page of the content area where 'content creators' are allowed to make pages.

All pages under this parent will now require additional steps before publishing.

[image: Screenshot of the add workflow page]